# File not found error while uploading image file from client to server

Tags: java, upload, filenotfoundexception

I tried uploading an image file from client to server but I'm getting following error on server console:
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat7/imageFolder/images/download_1412168176953.jpg (No such file or directory)

The code to do this is a follows :

```
 String dirName = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "imageFolder"   ;
    File theDir = new File(dirName);

    if (!theDir.exists()) {
        if (!theDir.mkdirs()) {
            if (!theDir.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("fail to create directory " + dirName);
            }
        }
    }

    dirName += File.separator + images;
    theDir = new File(dirName);

    if (!theDir.exists()) {
        if (!theDir.mkdirs()) {
            if (!theDir.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("fail to create directory " + dirName);
            }
        }
    }
 Long date = new Date().getTime();

        fileName = dirName + File.separator + basename + "_" + date.toString() + "." + extname;

        File f = new File(fileName);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        outputStream.write(file.getBytes());
        fileList.add(fileName);
```

Anyone plz help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your file name is generated from current timestamp. The image of same file name is not getting created.

Comment: In `outputStream.write(file.getBytes());` where is `file` being declared?